# scrapy: how to collect items that show only by clicking on "show more item" button?

Tags: python-2.7

I use scrapy to collect products from the site:https://www.coop.nl/boodschappen/groenten-en-aardappelen
But some of the products are displayed only by pressing the button:
Toon meer producten
I tried to use Roll to enter the button but without success
it collect only 12 first items that shown.
How can I collect data on these products?

this is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
import re

class Product(scrapy.Item):
    barcode = scrapy.Field()
    name = scrapy.Field()

class BarcodessSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "coop_barcodes"
    allowed_domains = ["www.coop.nl"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.coop.nl/boodschappen/groenten-en-aardappelen/roerbakgroenten/roerbakgroenten"
    ]

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('https:.*',),  
                           restrict_xpaths='//*[(@id = "showMoreProductsContainer")] | //*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "btn", " " ))]'),
                           callback='parse_item1',
                           follow=True),)

    items = []

    def parse_item1(self, response):
        for product in response.xpath('//@href'): 
            prod = product.root
            if re.match('\d{8}\d+',str(prod).split('/')[-1]) != None:
                 self.items.append(name)
        for item in self.items:
            yield item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sites that use dynamic loading typically have to send out HTTP requests to fetch new content, which can be caught by Chrome (I'm not sure how to do it in other browsers). Open the site in Chrome, press F12 and go to the Console tab. Right click the blank console and choose "LogXMLHttpRequests". Then press the "Load more" button (or whatever that triggers loading). You should see one or maybe a few URLs pop up in the console. The one with the GET request is what you want. In your site, the [link](https://www.coop.nl/actions/ViewAjax-Start?PageNumber=1&PageSize=12&SortingAttribute=&ViewType=&TargetPipeline=ViewStandardCatalog-ProductPaging&CategoryName=11&SearchParameter=%26%40QueryTerm%3D*%26ContextCategoryUUID%3DFbQKAQCNv.4AAAFWQudMRzCy%26OnlineFlag%3D1&CatalogID=COOP&AjaxCall=true) gets you a nice JSON list of all products that was loaded.

In these cases I would suggest scraping directly via these URLs (note in the URL how you can change PageNumber and PageSize to navigate) rather than the main site.